# Object.create vs new in terms of prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I have searched a lot about it but I couldn't find any direct answer to it

**Why we can't access prototype property/method of an object created using `Object.create()` but we can using `new` keyword?**

Let us consider a constructor function `Greeting` as follows:

```
function Greeting() {   
}
Greeting.prototype.byeBye = function(){
    console.log("Have a good day!")
}
```

Now I create an object from this constructor using `Object.create()` method

```
var Stanley = Object.create(Greeting)
console.log(Stanley.byeBye())

Output -  Error: Stanley.byeBye is not a function
```

Which means `byeBye()` function cannot be accessed directly using **Stanley** object

If you check for *Stanley* object in console, then you will find the following structure:

[image]

However if we use the **`new`** keyword to create the object, then we can access `byeBye()` prototype function directly

```
var Hamley = new Greeting()
console.log(Hamley.byeBye())

Output: Have a good day!
```

On checking the structure of *Hamley* object in console, we get it like this:

[image]

My doubt is that why we can't access prototype property/method of an object created using **`Object.create()`** but we can using the **`new`** keyword.

Another doubt is that why in case of `Object.create()`, prototype method `byeBye()` comes under seperate property in `__proto__` called as '**`prototype`**'. Whereas in case of **`new`**, `byeBye()` function is directly available under `__proto__`.

**Note:** Please check the links to open the images related to second doubt

Thanks to anyone who answers to this post!

Answer (score 2):

The object you give to `Object.create` should be the prototype you want the new object to have. You're passing in the constructor function, so that's making the constructor function the prototype of the object. You probably meant to use the same object `new` would use, which is on the `prototype` property of the constructor.

So instead of:

```
var Stanley = Object.create(Greeting)
```

you want

```
var Stanley = Object.create(Greeting.prototype)
// ---------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
```

Live Example:

```js
function Greeting() {   
}
Greeting.prototype.byeBye = function(){
    console.log("Have a good day!");
}

var Stanley = Object.create(Greeting.prototype);
Stanley.byeBye();
```

Comment: Just a helpful sidenote, the only difference between calling `new Greeting` and `Object.create(Greeting.prototype)` is that the `Greeting` constructor is not invoked, but otherwise the object returned is identical if the constructor does not contain a `return` statement with an expression.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Indeed -- specifically, if the constructor doesn't return an object (returning a primitive, or null, is ignored).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, T.J.Crowder. But I have a doubt here. When `var Stanley = Object.create(Greeting)` is used, then `Greeting` function becomes prototype of `Stanley`. `byeBye()` is prototype method of `Greeting` constructor. So why this method doesn't come under `__proto__` of `Greeting` constructor? Why does it appear inside something called `prototype` of the constructor when checked in console?

Comment: @VaibhavSharma: `byeBye` is a property on `Greeting.prototype`, not `Greeting`. If you use `Greeting` (the function) as the prototype, `byeBye` is nowhere in the object's prototype chain.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I have got it very clearly now. If we check in console for `Greeting` alone, then it shows just that function alone. We cannot find any prototype method in it. However, if we check for `Greeting.prototype`, then we can find our mystic method `byeBye()` in console. Well thanks a lot for your help. Keep up the good work !!